# Reference to other styled component doesn't work

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

Why in this case `${InputBox}:focus & { ... }` doesn't work in `styled-components`? Is any other way to make this work?

```
export const InputBox = styled.input`
position: absolute;
border: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
background: transparent;
&:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}

export const Placeholder = styled.div`
margin-top: 0px;
${InputBox}:focus & {
    margin-top: 50px;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: can you explain what do you want to achieve? Why do you have an ampersand in the selector?

Answer (score 0):

as your `InputBox` is rendered as html element, you many need target this by element name or className to override the style.

```
export const InputBox = styled.input`
position: absolute;
border: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
background: transparent;
&:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}`

export const Placeholder = styled.div`
margin-top: 0px;
input:focus & {
    margin-top: 50px;
    color: white;
}`
```